# React - Redux - this.props return always undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I have the following code

store/index.js

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = {
    auth: { isAuthenticated: false },
    error: { message: null },
    tracks: [],
    uploadedTrack: {}
};
```

store/reducers/index.js

```
import auth from './auth';
import error from './error';
import {tracks, uploadedTrack} from './tracks';

export default combineReducers({
    auth,
    tracks,
    uploadedTrack,
    error
});
```

store/reducers/tracks.js

```
import {UPLOADED_TRACK, SET_CURRENT_USER_TRACK} from '../actionTypes';

export const tracks = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USER_TRACK:
            return action.tracks;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export const uploadedTrack = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case UPLOADED_TRACK:
            return action.track;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

store/actions/tracks.js

```
export const setTrack = tracks => ({
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER_TRACK,
    tracks
});

export const setUploadedTrack = track => ({
    type: UPLOADED_TRACK,
    track
});

export const getUserTrack = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        try {
            const {token, ...tracks} = await api.call('get', 'tracks/user');

            dispatch(setTrack(tracks));
            dispatch(removeError());
        } catch (err) {
            const {error} = err.response.data;
            dispatch(addError(error.message));
        }
    };
};
```

components/trackList.jsx

```
componentDidMount() {
        const {getUserTrack} = this.props;
        getUserTrack();
    }

render() {
        var {authType} = this.props;
        const {auth} = this.props;
        const {tracks} = this.props;

        console.log("Track: ", tracks)
```

All seems works because my "tracks" on Redux store contains my list of six tracks, but when i try to print this information from the "tracks" variable on the console this print "undefined".
The strange things is that my "call" on the console contains my six tracks...
Can you help me? 
I don't know where is my errors, i try to apply the solutions find on the web but nothing working.

Comment: Did you add: 

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

To your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show how you map your redux state to your component ? If your redux store store contains your six tracks but you can't display them in your react component, the problem is probably how you bind your store to your component (When you call your connect() in your `components/trackList.jsx`).

Comment: Yes, i've store with this line of code: export default connect(
    store => ({
        auth: store.auth,
        tracks: store.track,
    }),
    {
        getUserTrack
    }
)(Profile); obviously i have imported the getUserTrack from my actions on the top of my page

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo in your comment or if it is in your code also but you forgot the `s` at the end of `tracks` when binding it to your component.

if should be `connect(store => ({ auth: store.auth, tracks: store.tracks })`

Comment: Oh... this help me! now i can see my tracks! :) thanks, but this generate an another problem: when i try .map to my tracks generate tracks.map is not a function... :O do you know why?

Comment: This is probably because when you retrieve your list of tracks from your API: `const {token, ...tracks} = await api.call('get', 'tracks/user');` the variable `tracks` is an object, not an array and objects do not have built-in map methods.

Try using `Object.keys(tracks).map` instead of `tracks.map`

Comment: Not working for me.. i've tried to print this `console.log(tracks.length)` but this returned an "undefined". But `console.log(tracks[0])` print my first record... it looks that my tracks is not an array but yes **twisted**

Comment: This permits to .map but not to enter to the tracks field. Ex. `var singleTrack = Object.keys(tracks).map(track => ( <li>{track.name}</li> ) );`, more if i try  `console.log(Object.keys(tracks));` this print an array of ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]. This looks strange things to me, it almost seems that Redux store doesn't take the return data well. :/

Comment: `Object.keys(tracks).map(key => tracks[key]).map(track => <li>{track.name}</li>)`

Comment: The problem here is that the tracks you store inside your redux store is not an array, it is an object. A better solution would be to transform your tracks object into an array after receiving it just before updating your store. (inside your `getUserTrack` action). Or even better to have your API send an array in the first place.

Comment: I've said thank you for your time and answers! I think the better way is that the API send an array. Thanks again! :)